# Bitmap Recycle Error

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

I have a high resolution image in my application. I am scaling and setting it to background  of a fragment in onResume() and recycling it onPause().

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(obj_bitmap == null)
    {
        obj_bitmap = ImageUtility.decodeResourceBitmapImage(getResources(), R.drawable.background, int_display_width, int_display_height);
        Drawable obj_drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), obj_bitmap);
        linearlayout_event_list_parent.setBackground(obj_drawable);
    }
    autocompletetextview_search.clearFocus();
    super.onResume();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onPause()
 */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if(obj_bitmap != null && !obj_bitmap.isRecycled())
    {
        obj_bitmap.recycle();
        obj_bitmap = null;
        System.gc();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

obj_bitmap is my bitmap object. Image resolution is 1440X2582.
Error:

```
> 04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833): Process: com.eventizon, PID: 19833
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@64da1d00
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1084)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:844)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:490)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14493)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1086)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14511)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1577)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2407)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2279)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1909)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 11:56:58.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19833):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the application enters "onPause", it may still be displayed at the moment, and therefore recycling the still used bitmap makes it crash. If you really want to do that there, clear the background first so it no longer uses that bitmap.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wildcopper . I was not able to figure out that it was all due to onPause .